# undefined method `id' for "#<User:0x00007fe6d52c9c50>":String in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

i did a button in html that when you press it send to the controller the current_user, so after that i want to work with that user in the controller but when i try to access to the atribute of the object user appears a problem saying that my object user is a string and a really don t know how trasform it to a object again, this is my code and the error:

Error:

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#show
undefined method `id' for "#<User:0x00007fe6d52c9c50>":String
Extracted source (around line #66):

puts params[:petition]  user = params[:petition]    puts user.id    # user = User.find(params[:petition])   # puts datos.email  # $list_of_petition.push(user)
```

code of the html:

```
<!--hacer boton de peticion-->

<form action=<%article_path(@article)%>>
<label for="petition">mail del usuario que se <br> convertira en moderador:</label>
<button name="petition" value=<%=current_user%> type="submit">pedir moderar</button>

</form>
```

code of my Articlescontroller:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @article.posts
  puts "fijate men"
  puts params[:q]
  puts params[:petition]
  if params[:q] != nil
    @answer = Search()
    puts "aqui deveria ir respuesta"
    puts @answer
  end
  if params[:petition] != nil
    puts "miar aqui plspslpsl"
    puts params[:petition].inspect
    @respond = ask_to_admin()
  end
end

def ask_to_admin
  puts "hola"
  puts params[:petition]
  user = params[:petition]
  puts user.id
```

i know that there is a way replacing the `current_user` for `current_user.id`and after in the controller make `user = User.find(params[:petition])` but i dont what that, what to send the whole user.

Comment: You should really use a form helper. And, you should pass around the `current_user.id` as a hidden value using the `hidden_field_tag`. You don't marshal an ActiveRecord instance the way you're trying. You may *want* to, but it's not the way it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `user=params[:petition]` means assigning `user` variable a string.

You can't pass `current_user` through `params`. Instead, you should pass the `current_user.id` and in your controller, you can do something like below:

```
user = User.find params[:id]
```

Always remember `params` is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` and behaves like a `hash` object and when you try to pass `current_user` or any other `record` within `params`, Actually you're just passing a String. So always pass the record id in `params`

Comment: Good answer. Just to pick nits for a moment, `params` is actually an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` which is hash-like, but not a `Hash`.

Comment: @jvillian Thanks for correcting! Updated the answer.

Comment: that mean that there isnt a way to pass current_user to the controller like a object and not like a string?

Comment: @mrpepo877 You can't do that. What is the problem with just passing the id?

Comment: just to know, i thought that passing the information in that way could be insecure :)

Comment: Why do you think that's not secure? If for some reason, you're not comfortable with passing an id in params, look into using slugs instead of an id. Refer to https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Unless if you've a very specific usecase where you don't want to expose the actual id, It is completely ok to pass an id in params.

Comment: because the link that generate is the following:
    http://192.168.99.101:3000/articles/1?petition=5
and some persons can change the 5 for 1 or other and do the petition with another id :(

Comment: This is something related to Authorization.

Comment: You might want to use pandit or cancancan gem to handle Authorization, or even a simple before_action can also help.